# Paint Component wont run

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I'm absolutely stumped as to why Paint Component isn't running in this code:

```
public class GraphicsWindow extends JPanel {
    public static final int Width = 1000, Height = 800;
    GraphicsWindow(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Width, Height));
    }
    public void PaintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        for(int i = 0; i < Width/10; i++){
            g.drawLine(i * 10, 0, i*10, Height);
        }
          System.out.println("paint ran");
    }

}
```

Main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsWindow Graphics = new GraphicsWindow();
        Graphics.setBackground(Color.green);
        Graphics.setSize(1000, 800);
        JFrame Window = new JFrame("Snake");
        Window.add(Graphics);
        Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Window.setBounds(650, 200, 1200, 1000);
        Window.setVisible(true);
        Graphics.repaint();
    }
```

I have been at it for about an hour looking at forum page after forum page and gotten nowhere. I can tell that it is the paint component not running because the console never gets the "Paint ran" printout. I am sorry ahead of time if it is a really stupid mistake and for the possibly messy code, I am a bit new to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java names are case sensitive:

```
 public void PaintComponent(Graphics g){
```

should be:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
```

When you override a method you should be using:

```
@Override
public void PaintComponent(Graphics g){
```

and the compiler will give you an error message when you don't override an existing method.

Variable names should NOT start with an upper case. Learn Java conventions by looking at examples and follow those examples.

```
Graphics.repaint();
```

There is no need for the repaint(). Swing will paint all the components when the frame is made visible.

Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics and working examples to get you started.

Comment: Your right! I should have noticed that with my call to super.